# How to gitignore a specific file with it's minified version in one rule?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore a specific file: ***myFile.js*** AND it's minified version ***myFile.min.js*** in the same rule.

I tried: ***myFile[.min].js*** with no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following since gitignore accepts wildcards:

```
myFile*.js
```